# Modify a .webarchive from within cocoa and write out again

Tags: cocoa, dom, pyobjc, webarchive

I have access to a .webarchive file. I have so far managed to create a webarchive (using PyObjC) from the file. I wish to modify some elements in the DOM tree and write the modified data out.

I guess I need access to some root DOM tree (the webarchive is one web page, with no links) given a WebArchive.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this in Cocoa?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (haven't checked as yet)

```
from Foundation import *
import objc
import WebKit
from WebKit import *
d=NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile_("/tmp/x.webarchive")
ws=WebArchive.alloc().initWithData_(d)
wv=WebView.alloc().initWithFrame_frameName_groupName_(((100, 100),(100,100)), "foo",None)
mf=wv.mainFrame()
mf.loadArchive_(ws)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to load the WebArchive into the WebView looks correct (I'm not very familiar with PyObjC). Modifying the DOM is pretty easy using methods from the WebKit API ([documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/ObjC_classic/_index.html)). The tricky bit is once you've modified the DOM and you want to write the modifications back to the WebArchive. Simply saving a new WebArchive won't work because this won't preserve your modifications, so you need to write the new source. Here's some code that will do that (here the WebView is `webview` and the original WevArchive is located at archivePath and the modified version will be written there as well):

```
//Get the string representation of the current DOM tree
NSString *sourceString = [(DOMHTMLElement *)[[[webview mainFrame] DOMDocument] documentElement] outerHTML];
NSData *sourceData = [sourceString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Load the archive from disk to a dictionary (it's a plist)
NSMutableDictionary *archive = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:archivePath]];
//Modify the main HTML
[(NSMutableDictionary *)[archive objectForKey:@"WebMainResource"] setObject:sourceData forKey:@"WebResourceData"];
//Write the plist back out
NSData *data = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:archive format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];
[data writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:ArchivePath] atomically:YES];
```

This is a little bit of a hack because it relies on the internal structure of the archive format which is undocumented, but I think you can pretty safely assume it won't change drastically.